# which npm library is good for flowchart display?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, graph, antd

i have a scenario where i have to display data in attached flowchart way. using react for this. which library is good to use for this scenario?[image: graph type flowchart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are looking for.
If you need to quickly and easily parse large diagrams then I'd suggest GraphViz React:
https://github.com/DomParfitt/graphviz-react
Pros:

- Easy to code
- Easy to parse information
- Standard graph language

Cons:

- Not very customizable

If you need pretty and complex diagrams with alot of detail then I'd suggest React Diagrams:
https://github.com/projectstorm/react-diagrams
Pros:

- Very customizable
- Great level detail

Cons:

- Harder to code